# Unable to disable electron menu item

Tags: electron, menuitem

It seems, I cant find any answer for it on the web.

I tried to disable the electron menu, on a click event, but it fails.

The code is something like this `menuItem.enable = false;` but it doesn't work. I tried to do a console log, but everything seems fine with no exceptions or error.

Comment: My bad it should be ```enabled``` not ```enable```.

Answer (score 7):

You can look it up in the [electron api](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu-item/).

Just as @zer09 commented it should be

```
menuItem.enabled = false;
```

The documentation says this:

> enabled Boolean (optional) - If false, the menu item will be greyed out and unclickable.

Comment: It would appear this does not work when using remote /:  I am not able to disable menu items from renderer process when the menu was made in main.